# How to get Rancher scripts code when add agent to nodes hosts?

Tags: docker, cluster-computing, agent, rancher

Normally, get that code on master host's dashboard:

```
$ sudo docker run --rm --privileged -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /var/lib/rancher:/var/lib/rancher rancher/agent:v1.2.2 http://192.168.0.100:8080/v1/scripts/5D8B3FD489C00C7F361A:2483142400000:WvMClyNFLXQnT9pLuii3D0sYA
```

If want to deploy multiple nodes automatic to other hosts, it's necessary to get this code from master:

> 5D8B3FD489C00C7F361A:2483142400000:WvMClyNFLXQnT9pLuii3D0sYA

Then every node just add agent with this code is good. Is it right?

But, how to get it by cli from master?

Comment: Are those rancher API keys that are generated once?

Comment: @AlexKarshin Do you mean get from here: `192.168.0.100:8080/v1/agents` ? I tried to search it but didn't find the code.

Comment: No, I'm asking where you are getting the codes

Comment: @AlexKarshin From dashboard. This page: `192.168.0.100:8080/env/1a5/infra/hosts/add?driver=custom`. Step 5: `Copy, paste, and run the command below to register the host with Rancher:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rancher has API, which enables you to interact with it remotely. What you require is called `registrationTokens`. Now, how to access them.

First, set up API tokens in your Rancher. Go to `API -> Keys -> Add Account API Key` and create the keys. If you can't find the buttons, your URL would be `192.168.0.100:8080/env/1a5/api/keys`.

Now you know the keys and from remote host you can do something like this:

```
curl -u "${RANCHER_ACCESS_KEY}:${RANCHER_SECRET_KEY}" \
-X GET \
'http://192.168.0.100:8080/v2-beta/projects/1a5/registrationtokens'
```

Your result will be a JSON with required data:

```
{
...
    "data": [
    {
        "id": "1c3",
        "type": "registrationToken",
        "links": {
            ...
        },
        "actions": {
            ...
        },
        ...
        "command": "sudo docker run --rm --privileged -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /var/lib/rancher:/var/lib/rancher rancher/agent:v1.2.2 http://192.168.0.100:8080/v1/scripts/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA:0000000000000:ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ",
        ...
    }],
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and awesome answer! Maybe not `POST` mehtod but `GET` can get command. If use `POST`, I got `null` command. And, it is necessary to add a project code into the url. Here should be `1a5`. So there comes another question: is it possible to get that code in the terminal(cli)? Also, it seems that should generated API key and secret on the dashboard, but can it been generated from command? I finilly want to do the all installation automictly using Ansible. By the way, do you know the right way to deploy to multiple master and nodes host? Ansible or else?

Comment: oh, indeed, thank you, I fixed those issues. To use that remotely from terminal, use cURL or any other thing, that sends GET requests. Nothing else can help you here.